# How chat applications work without repeated ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, database, chat

I tried creating a chat application in Php and i used the below logic.

1.Get input from user-1 and insert it into the table.

2.Run an ajax function every 5 seconds to look for new entries in the table and display to user-2.

3.vice-versa.

This procedure is really too very slow and the browser hangs often.

How does the real-time chat application actually works ? Can the database trigger an event automatically in the front-end so that we need not hit the database every 5 seconds? If yes, how it is done?

Thanks.

Comment: I second that, look into Node.js. In fact many Node.js tutorials actually go through implementing a chat application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That strategy is called **polling** and it served us good in the early 2000s, but it has done its time.

A better enhancement is **long-polling**. We request a webpage, but the server doesn't immediately respond but waits until there's new information available. When the clients receives the new information, it immediately sends a new request and so forth.

Now in 2015, we have **HTML5 Websockets** and **HTML5 SSE** (Server Sent Events), that allows both the client and the server to send data whenever data (on either side) is available.

You might consider using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) (javascript) or [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) (PHP) on your server.

Comment: Can it be done with PHP also? Can you please provide some code on how to do it with PHP or at least give a link???

Comment: Yes, you can use websockets with PHP. Use Ratchet for that purpose. There is a nice tutorial for a chat application on this link : http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

Comment: Thanks!!! You should put that in your answer as well.☺

Answer (score 1):

Or just long polling, like facebook...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Websockets, they are supported natively in modern browsers.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

And use a PHP library to use them server side : http://socketo.me